# Deploying Keyrock Idm on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, node.js, kubernetes, fiware, idm

I have 2 pods(1mysql+1idm) on Kubernetes Cluster (1 master+1 worker node on VirtualBox)

Although Keyrock creates the idm database, it cannot be migrated.
So the superuser is never inserted into db and many fields of the tables are missing.

Below are presented the idm's logs from the relative container:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find out about the concret problem with your installation, I would need more information about config and version of MySql and Keyrock.

To not have that problems, I would recommend using the keyrock helm-chart:
https://github.com/FIWARE/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/keyrock

Its tested to run with the Bitnami-MySql(https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql) Chart out of the box.

Comment: I am using the fiware/idm:7.6.0 image of keyrock and the mysql:5.7.21 image of mysql.It seems that it's working when i deploy first the mysql and keyrock deployments , and after they are initialized i must deploy the mysql service in order to be connected with the keyrock. May i need an init container for keyrock , because of its dependance of mysql?

Comment: Do you use set the IDM_DB_SEED environment variable? If its set to true, keyrock should setup the database on startup. The mysql should already run before starting keyrock.